# How to handle duplicated recommendations in an online experiment for the recommender system

Tags: recommendation-engine, experimental-design

I am about to run an online user experiment to compare different strategies of the recommender system. 
I will compare 18 strategies and each strategy produces five recommendations, thus I have to ask subjects to evaluate 90 recommendations in total. 
However, the strategies make duplicated recommendations (i.e., some recommendations appear in several strategies).

(i) In the current design, each page provides five recommendations made by one strategy. 
After a user inputs evaluations for all of them, another page shows up, where five recommendations by another strategy are given. 
Thus, a user sometimes sees recommendations which he already evaluated. 
I think this design is widely used in previous works, although how to handle duplicated recommendations has not been discussed extensively.

(ii) Or is it reasonable to first extract all unique recommendations, split them into different pages, and show them in the random order? 
I think this design makes the experiment shorter. 
But this design has not been used, to the best of my knowledge.

If you have a suggestion or know a paper related to it, please give it to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not trying to solve a programming problem, but is rather a UI/UX problem.

Answer (score 1):

If those algorithms are different and they generate the recommendations in a different way, then even if they generate some similar recommendations you should definitely keep those recommendations as if you don't keep them, then you changed the recommendation results for some algorithms and therefore, your experiment will lose its soundness. When they generate some similar recommendations, it means some items are just so favorable for some users that you cannot stop them from being recommended no matter what algorithm you are using. So you should keep them. You should somehow explain why this happens (something like what I explained here) to users that will evaluate those recommendations so that they don't mind seeing them again and again.